# How to force EMF not to manipulate reference ids

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, bpmn, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

Having the following code I'm loading a BPMN model.

```
// dummy URI, loading done through input stream
URI uri = URI.createURI("data.bpmn");
ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(uri, "org.eclipse.bpmn2.content-type.xml");
resource.load(contentStream, null);
```

Saving the resource `resource.save(outputStream, null);` manipulates the output and adds `data.bpmn#` to references:

```
<bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_StartEvent_1" bpmnElement="data.bpmn#StartEvent_1">
    <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="162.0" y="182.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel id="BPMNLabel_1" labelStyle="data.bpmn#BPMNLabelStyle_1">
            <dc:Bounds height="15.0" width="68.0" x="146.0" y="218.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
</bpmndi:BPMNShape>
```

Where it looks like this coming from the input stream:

```
<bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_StartEvent_1" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
    <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="162.0" y="182.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel id="BPMNLabel_1" labelStyle="BPMNLabelStyle_1">
            <dc:Bounds height="15.0" width="68.0" x="146.0" y="218.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
</bpmndi:BPMNShape>
```

Is there a way to force EMF not to manipulate the references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
XMLResource resource = (XMLResource) resourceSet.createResource(modelUri, "org.eclipse.bpmn2.content-type.xml");
XMLResource.URIHandler uriHandler = new URIHandlerImpl() {
    @Override
    public URI deresolve(URI uri) {
        // make sure references are stored without # URI prefix
        return URI.createURI(uri.fragment());
    }
};
resource.getDefaultSaveOptions().put(XMLResource.OPTION_URI_HANDLER, uriHandler);

resource.load(inputStream, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this :

```
 URI uri = URI.createURI("data.bpmn");
```

to

```
 URI.createPlatformResourceURI("/full/workspace/path/data.bpmn");
```

you have to register any package definition in data.bpmn to EPackage with the ResourceSet’s/global package registry...

if you're loading data.bpmn from a Stream , XML etc ...

[**The EMF Persistence API**](https://books.google.com/books?id=ff-9ZYhvPwwC&pg=PA299&lpg=PA299&dq=The+EMF+Persistence+API&source=bl&ots=yAUrF1qNsI&sig=pqdpvyMvyZ3FIlXTY5rhfVNjifc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Yk0pVY2LC4bnUue0gZgG&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=The%20EMF%20Persistence%20API&f=false)

The Resource interface includes a second version of the save() and load() methods, which include a stream argument:

void save(OutputStream outputstream,
          Map options) throws IOException;
void load(InputStream inputStream, Map options) throws IOException;
You might think that this implies that EMF resources are inherently "stream based." Although most resources used with EMF tend to be stream based, including the XML resources provided with EMF, non-stream-based (for example, relational database) resources can also be implemented....

Comment: The resource.save(null); was a wrong, I actually use resource.save(outputStream, null); If I use createPlatformResourceURI() the "StartEvent_1" is turned into "#StartEvent_1", also if I use createFileURI(). Is there some option to handle it?